# SQLAlchemy updating a value in a row dynamically after filter_by

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am new to both python and SQLAlchemy. I am on `python 3`

I created a class `testtbl`  to manipulate tables. One function is the `update`  where I pass :

`myfilter = {'origin_source_id':'MX01’}.`

find this row in `mysql` table where `origin_source_id = ‘MX01'`

`updatevalue = {'origin_source_id':'CAL01’}`

replace the found origin_source_id by ‘CAL01;

**The call**

```
testtbl.update_row(myfilter,updatevalue)
```

**The function**

```
def update_row(self,locaterowfilter,updatevalue):
    self.Session.query( self.TableClass ).filter_by( **locaterowfilter ).update( updatevalue )
```

I receive the following error

```
target_cls = query._mapper_zero().class_ 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute ‘class_’
```

I have no idea how to deal with it.

Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Please take some time to format your question properly, as it is quite hard to read in its current form. Start each line of a code block with 4 spaces, on top of existing indentation. Also make sure that your question is a [mcve] (read the linked help page with care). When asking these kinds of debugging questions it is usually also better to include the entire traceback, not just the error message. And please format tracebacks as code blocks for readability.

Comment: sorry for that , my first post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is the result of passing a [`Table`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table) object as the primary entity of a query and trying to use [`Query.update()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.update):

```
In [26]: t = Table('t', metadata,
    ...:           Column('a', Integer))

In [27]: session.query(t).update({'a': 1})
...
.../python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py in _do_pre_synchronize(self)
   1383     def _do_pre_synchronize(self):
   1384         query = self.query
-> 1385         target_cls = query._mapper_zero().class_
   1386 
   1387         try:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'class_'
```

which means that your `self.TableClass` is not a [mapped class](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_styles.html). If you wish to do updates on a `Table`, use the Core [`update()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.update) constructs:

```
stmt = self.TableClass.update().\
    where(and_(*[self.TableClass.c[key] == value
                 for key, value in locaterowfilter.items()])).\
    values(updatevalue)
self.Session.execute(stmt)
```